# Как правильно манипулировать флагами WindowStaysOnTopHint и WindowStaysOnBottomHint?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

В приложение есть маркер, который проверяет нажатие на него, если маркер активен, то закрепить окно поверх остальных, иначе не закреплять окно поверх остальных.

У меня вопрос, почему програма изсечает?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QCheckBox, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 40))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Checkbox") 

        self.b = QCheckBox("Awesome?",self)
        self.b.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)
        self.b.move(20,20)
        self.b.resize(320,40)

    def clickBox(self, state):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('OnTop')
            self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        else:
            print('BottomTop')
            self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: TypeError: setWindowFlag(self, Qt.WindowType, on: bool = True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'WindowFlags'

Answer (score 0):

Я заменил родительский класс `QMainWindow` на `QWidget` так как:

> [Qt Main Window Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework)
>
> ....
> Note. Создание главного окна без центрального виджета не поддерживается.
> У вас должен быть центральный виджет, даже если это просто заполнитель.
> ...

Чтобы переключить флаг единственного окна, вам нужно явно сбросить его.
Как вариант, попробуйте так:

```
import sys
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QCheckBox, \
    QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt 
   

class ExampleWindow(QWidget):                               # - QMainWindow
    def __init__(self):
#        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()                                  # !!!
        
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 40))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Checkbox") 

        self.b = QCheckBox("Awesome?", self)
        self.b.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)
        self.b.move(20, 20)
        self.b.resize(320, 40)

    def clickBox(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            print('OnTop')
            self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint, False)  # +++
            self.show()                                            # +++
            self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint, True)      # +++
        else:
            print('BottomTop')
            self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint, False)     # +++
            self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint, True)   # +++
        self.show()                                                # +++
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я делал по определенной иконки(тыкаю на иконку):

```
if ico_style == '':
            ico_style = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/PyQt5/ico/Style_1/Zakrep Off.png'
            self.exitAction_5.setIcon(QIcon(ico_style))#Закреп
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)#Или "ДА"
            self.show()
        elif ico_style == 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/PyQt5/ico/Style_1/Zakrep Off.png':
            ico_style = ''
            self.exitAction_5.setIcon(QIcon('C:/Users/user/Desktop/PyQt5/ico/Style_1/Zakrep.png'))#Закреп
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)#Или "НЕТ"
            self.show()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).